# MacBook Pro 9.2 Ubuntu 14.04 Full Link Quality Wireless Error

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, macbook

Hey guys I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on my mac, 
After being on the wifi for around 5 to 10 mins it randomly shows the signal as being maxed but the internet stops working all together. Here is what it shows when my wifi is working:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"vodafone-15B3"
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.417 GHz  Access Point: 08:7A:4C:EF:15:C4
      Bit Rate=144 Mb/s   Tx-Power=200 dBm
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=50/70 Signal level=-60 dBm
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

And here it is when it happens:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"vodafone-15B3"
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.417 GHz  Access Point: 08:7A:4C:EF:15:C4
      Bit Rate=144 Mb/s   Tx-Power=200 dBm
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=70/70 Signal level=15 dBm
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

I have installed the following drivers:

```
PCI (sysfs)  
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: 0c:4d:e9:c0:68:1f
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.134 firmware=57765-v1.37 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 memory:a0400000-a040ffff memory:a0410000-a041ffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 02
       serial: 90:fd:61:e4:fc:e6
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.141 (r415941) ip=192.168.1.3 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:17 memory:a0600000-a0603fff
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have the incorrect driver. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot and tell us if it is working as expected.

Comment: Did nothing mate, still the same :/

Comment: Please show us: lsmod | grep -e b43 -e wl -e brcm and also: lspci -nn -d 14e4  Thanks.

Comment: For first command:
ricky@ricky-MacBookPro:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for ricky: 

root@ricky-MacBookPro:/home/ricky# lsmod | grep -e b43 -e wl -e brcm

b43                   387371  0 

mac80211              630669  1 b43

cfg80211              484040  2 b43,mac80211

ssb                    62379  1 b43

bcma                   52096  1 b43

root@ricky-MacBookPro:/home/ricky#

Comment: For second:
root@ricky-MacBookPro:/home/ricky# lspci -nn -d 14e4
lspci: -d: ':' expected
root@ricky-MacBookPro:/home/ricky# lspci -nn -d 14e4:
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b4] (rev 10)
01:00.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Broadcom Corporation BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader [14e4:16bc] (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
root@ricky-MacBookPro:/home/ricky#